# Is there a way to force the client to match me with people from North America?

Tags: overwatch

I am temporarily visiting a South American country. When I play Overwatch, I keep getting matched with, well, people from South America, which makes sense.

... Unfortunately I can't understand whatever they're saying, so that makes teamwork a bit difficult and I'm essentially muting everybody every time I play.

Is there a way to force the client to match me with people from North America? The Blizzard launcher generalizes it too much to just "Americas".

Comment: Since it is so generalized you might have to invest in a VPN to trick the server into thinking you are in north america, but IDK if that would actually work

Comment: My educated guess would be no. Imagine you went to say Russia and didn't speak Russian. The client would still match you with people closest to you. There are likely workarounds (e.g. VPN) but I don't think there's an innate way to do this in Overwatch (read: most games)

Comment: I don't think this would be possible without VPN or something like that. What you can try is partying with a few friends who are in NA and look for a game, maybe you will get NA teammates. My guess would be that Blizzard will try to match you to closest people in order to have the best experience(=no lags)

Answer (score 3):

In the [upcoming social features](https://youtu.be/p_pnpZK_oYM?t=5m17s) update, the "Looking for Group" feature is being added, which let's you create a group based on certain criteria. With this, you can specify that you're looking to play with people with voicechat who also speak English.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? The answer provides an official solution to the problem of being matched up with people who don't speak their language.

Comment: @QuestionMarks: 7:04: "One thing to note about it is **it's not a matchmaking system.**  When you go to look for a group, you're either creating a group and showing it to other players, or you're browsing the list as somebody looking for a group, and then committing to join that group.  It's not automatically pulling players in and putting them into the system."  So this is not what OP asked for (which was "pick the North America region and don't make me think about it").

Comment: @Kevin It's definitely not the exact solution OP wanted, and if there's a way to select US servers or easily trick the placement system with breaking the rules or their ping, that'll be the better answer. It's a bit of a workaround, but it might also be OP's best option